# python-pip package not found on ubuntu 15.04 running as live usb

Tags: apt, python, pip

I'm trying to install `python-pip` using `apt-get` on ubuntu 15.04, but I get an error saying it's not found.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

According to launchpad it should exist.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/+source/python-pip

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` looks like

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 15.04 _Vivid Vervet_ - Release amd64 (20150422)]/ vivid main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` and then try again..

Comment: Tried that already.

Comment: Its in the universe repo..do you have it enabled in `sources.list`?

Comment: I'm running off a live usb until I get a new hard drive. That might be the issue. The source.list file doesn't seem complete  to me now that I look at it.

Comment: Check my answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`python-pip` package is available in the `universe` repository but your `/etc/apt/sources.list` does not contain the entry for the `universe` repository, as a result you will not be able to download anything from that repo unless you add it.

To add the `universe` repo to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, run:

```
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid universe" | sudo tee -a "/etc/apt/sources.list"
```

If you are interested in source files, then add this too:

```
echo "deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid universe" | sudo tee -a "/etc/apt/sources.list"
```

Run `sudo apt-get update` and now you can install `python-pip` by:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider first upgrading your not supported release.
Read: [How to upgrade from not supported Ubuntu using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1279805/78223)

Then:

1. Install `easy_install` by: `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools` command (for Python 3 use: `python3-setuptools`).
2. Install Pip by: `sudo python -m easy_install install pip` (for Python 3 use `python3`).