# How can I upgrade from 18.10 to current 20.04 version of ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, updates

Except for LTS Ubuntu doesn't support software updates from "cycled out" versions (like 19.04 just became and 18.10 before that)

[This was the best answer I could find online](https://askubuntu.com/a/1212699/1100450) it provides [this very useful blog post](https://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2020/02/21/upgrading-from-an-unsupported-ubuntu/) updated in April.

My issue is:

It provides a guide to trick your computer into updating from 18.10 to 19.04, as 19.10 was the current version at the beginning of this year the update from 19.04 was still supported and as such the user could then update to 19.10 the easy conventional way, after the 18.10 -> 19.04 passage.

My "strategy" was then to 18.10 -> 19.04 this way, do the same process but for 19.04 -> 19.10, and from 19.10 to 20.04 by updating the conventional way

Just as the blog post alerts, I changed all the links for the 'disco' version in the meta-release2 file into http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/

I also deleted all the entries for the 20.04 version in the meta-release2 file too

Still - I can't do it, and it gives me the following error:

```
Invalid package information 

After updating your package information, the essential package 
'ubuntu-minimal' could not be located. This may be because you have 
no official mirrors listed in your software sources, or because of 
excessive load on the mirror you are using. See /etc/apt/sources.list 
for the current list of configured software sources. 
In the case of an overloaded mirror, you may want to try the upgrade 
again later.
```

Comment: Save yourself the trouble, and do a fresh install of 20.04. It will be faster, give you a clean optimally performing system  and save you trouble afterwards.