# do-release-upgrade not finding next version

Tags: upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade a server currently running 19.04

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:    19.04
Codename:   disco
```

I'm trying to get it to upgrade to the current LTS 20.04 but not having any luck at all. I've set `prompt=normal` in the release-upgrades file but when I run `do-release-upgrade -c` I'm told the next version is `20.04 LTS` and not `19.10`

If I then try and run the upgrade regardless, it tells me that it isn't supported to upgrade straight to 20.04 (expected) but I've not found a way of forcing it to get the next release. It seems to be completely ignoring the prompt setting.

Is there a way I can specify the version or change something else to get it to pick up? I'm currently completely stuck on 19.04 which isn't ideal.

Comment: You waited too long: 19.10 reached End Of Life last week, and those repositories were withdrawn. 19.04 reached End Of Life six months ago. You have not received any security patches in six months. Consider marking your calendar next time; this is an easily avoidable problem.

Comment: If you don't want to have to upgrade every 6 months, I suggest sticking with an LTS release like 18.04 or 20.04. LTS releases come out every 2 years and are supported for 5 years, in the case of Ubuntu, and 3 years, in the case of other Ubuntu flavors (like Kubuntu)

Comment: FYI only - http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/07/17/ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2020/   (detail on the *fully-tested* upgrade window closing for older 19.04)

Comment: So basically there is NO way to upgrade, if the next version is also EOL? That's just wonderful

Comment: There are some hack-ish ways to do such upgrade. See [How to upgrade from 18.10 to 19.10, using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1208109/816190). The post was written when 18.10 and 19.04, both went EOL.

Comment: Great thanks,  I'll have a go at something like that. Would really rather not have to rebuild the entire server just to upgrade. I completely understand not supporting an old version but to make it basically impossible to upgrade from that seems absolutely insane to me!